# scp from remote server to local computer?

Tags: macos, file-transfer, scp

Ok, very very basic and simple question, but I'm a bit confused.

After ssh'ing to remote server, I want to transfer a file back to my computer...

The syntax is simple, of course: scp ./foo user@remote.host.location

That makes sense if I'm sending it to another server, but how do I configure it to send to my own box?  I'd think it would be as simple as username@home.ip.address but I can't figure out how to make it work!

Comment: Instead of copying from the remote server to your local computer, why not open Cyberduck (or FileZilla, or other SCP client to your need) from your Local Computer to the Remote Server? If you're trying to connect back from the Remote Server to your Local Computer, the assumption would be: your local PC is accessible from internet, and SSH daemon is running and allowing access from internet.

Comment: Well, that would be easy, wouldn't it?  :P  Unfortunately I'm trying to get files from NASA's supercomputer though two levels of RSA authentication, which something like FileZilla isn't really meant for... the command line scp is really the best route.

Comment: From your home pc: scp remote_user@remore_host:/path/to/file . The dot is necessary, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use SSH to transfer from remote to local in the same way that you would the other way round, you will need to setup an ssh server on your home pc (with relevant port forwarding etc) and initiate a second ssh connection to your local pc from within the ssh connection to your remote.

lets say your computer's public ip is home.ip.address as above
and your remote server IP is remote.host.location as above.

From your home pc initiate an ssh connection to remote.host.location as you normally would.
then from the remote shell, use scp with user@home.ip.address as the address as you suggested above.

The key is to setup your local pc to accept ssh connections.

Answer (score 0):

Another completely separate answer to my other;

It seems as though the scp command allows for host to local transfers.

The only difference being the source and target locations.

If we think of scp as having the following format;

> scp *source target*

We can see that the following abides by this rule;

> scp ./foo user@remote.host.location:/target

And by extension the below is a valid way of doing the other way around;

> scp user@remote.host.location:/target ./foo

I have not tested it but have seen it refered to [here](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).